# How to enable new Places autocomplete API

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I already have Map API enabled. Do I need a separate Places API key? Mine is showing that Places API is enabled, but no key is there.

Also, as far as I know, both goes under `android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need separate API KEY for places api. You just need to enable the places api from Google Console.